# Displaying image from database issue

Tags: php, database, image

I am trying to display an image from a database however its not working how I expected it to. I've tried to understand why but I don't... the image isn't being displayed and I am getting a lot of random scrambled lettering instead.

this is the php that I have at the top of the page:

```html
<?php
if (is_resource($browse)) mysql_free_result($browse); 
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/clubbit.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$maxRows_browse = 12;
$pageNum_browse = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_browse'])) {
  $pageNum_browse = $_GET['pageNum_browse'];
}
$startRow_browse = $pageNum_browse * $maxRows_browse;

mysql_select_db($database_clubbit, $clubbit);
$query_browse = "SELECT * FROM images";
$query_limit_browse = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_browse, $startRow_browse, $maxRows_browse);
$browse = mysql_query($query_limit_browse, $clubbit) or die(mysql_error());
$row_browse = mysql_fetch_assoc($browse);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_browse'])) {
  $totalRows_browse = $_GET['totalRows_browse'];
} else {
  $all_browse = mysql_query($query_browse);
  $totalRows_browse = mysql_num_rows($all_browse);
}
$totalPages_browse = ceil($totalRows_browse/$maxRows_browse)-1;
?>
```

this is the form i am trying to use to display the image:

```html
<section class="sectionFull">
  <h1>Browse Clubs</h1>
   <section class="sectionClubs">
     <div class="thumbnail"> 
      <form method="POST" name="clubs" id="clubs">
            
    <?php do { ?>
      <img src='<?php echo $row_browse['image']; ?>' />
 <?php } while ($row_browse = mysql_fetch_assoc($browse)); ?>

 <input name="imageID" type="hidden" id="imageID" value="<?php echo $row_browse['imageID']; ?>">

    </form> 
    </div>
 </section>
</section>
```

I have an image in the database, but the result is the image not showing and a load of weird characters appearing underneath it.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to put binary data into the src attribute value?

Comment: I have set the image column type to BLOB but when I try and set the attribute field to binary this error appears:  "#1064 - you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'binary not null' at line 1".              But when I saved the table with the attribute field empty and tried to insert data into the table it said ''Binary - do not edit (63.7KiB)" in the value column so i didn't worry about the error. Is that why this is happening do you think? Cos the attribute field isnt set to binary?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to stick binary data into a src attribute.  To do that you need to encode it and prefix it so the browser will recognize it as a Data URI.  You might find it easier to create a separate script that will return the image with the proper header, and use the URL as the src for the img tag.